# Extra spaces occurs when I use replace_names to remove names using R, textclean, stringr?

Tags: r, regex, replace, space

I am studying stringr and textclean in R. I want to delete the names in a bunch of mails. I find something that really confuses me:

```
a <- 'a<b>Jone Smith<br></b>afef</div>'
```

If I directly do:

```
> replace_names(a,replacement = '')
[1] "a<b>Jone Smith<br>< / b>afef< / div>"
```

You can see names cannot be deleted. I guess this is because `>` and `<` are immediately next to the names so names cannot be identified. At the same time, some weird spaces occur in `</b>` and `</div>`.

So here is my way to deal with:

```
a <- 'a<b>Jone Smith<br></b>afef</div>'
a <- str_replace_all(string = a,pattern = '>',replacement = '> ')
a <- str_replace_all(string = a,pattern = '<',replacement = ' <')
a
replace_names(a,replacement = '')
```

I want to add a space before < and befind < so as to make names separated. But the result is:

```
> a
[1] "a <b> Jone Smith <br>  </b> afef </div> "
> replace_names(a,replacement = '')
[1] "a <b>   <br> < / b> afef < / div>"
```

You can see that a means the spaces are added successfully. But after replace_names, more spaces are added in `</b>` and `</div>` again. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `textclean::replace_names` makes a call to `textclean::replace_tokens`, which in turn makes a call to `textclean:::replace_string_elements_generic`. This last function tokenizes the string with `textshape::split_token`, replaces elements found in a vector of names, and then `paste`s everything back together and removes extra whitespace. Certain punctuation characters, including `/`, are treated as tokens, so when the string is pasted together with `paste(x, collapse = " ")` they are surrounded by whitespace. There is a final call to `gsub("(\\s+)([.!?,;:])", "\\2", out, perl = TRUE)` to remove whitespace from the punctuation characters, but `/` is not affected.

You can try filing an issue on GitHub, or send a pull request with a fix, but I doubt anything will happen because `/` is frequently surrounded by whitespace in normal language (see this [SE answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2134) for reference). Although, the developers might be open to a special case dealing with HTML tags.

I think it would make more sense to just deal with it on a case-by-case basis. Try either removing the tags or adding space, removing the names, and then removing the whitespace again:

```r
library(stringr)
library(textclean)

## Remove tags.
a %>% replace_html %>% replace_names

# [1] "a   afef."


## Add whitespace, remove names, remove whitespace.
a %>% 
    str_replace_all("([<>])", " \\1 ") %>% 
    replace_names %>% 
    str_replace_all(" ?([<>/]) ?", "\\1")

# [1] "a<b> <br></b>afef</div>."
```